# How to linearly order the set of all subsets of real numbers?

Tags: real-numbers, order-theory, cardinals, continuum-theory

I wondered if there are linearly ordered sets of any cardinality. As I understand it, there are. But I want to see at least one concrete example of a linearly ordered set which cardinality is greater than continuum. Not the fact of existence, but a concrete example with a concrete way of setting the order. For example, for the set of all subsets of real numbers.

Comment: The answer to your first question is a definite yes, if you assume axiom of choice. We can use the [von Neumann cardinal assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment) to equate any cardinal with an ordinal, which are well-ordered (and hence linearly ordered) sets. Still assuming choice, we also have the [well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), which states that any set can be well-ordered (and hence linearly ordered). I'm not sure how much we can recover without choice though, or how constructive we could be.

Comment: In fact, in a precise sense you cannot show "explicitly" that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is linearly orderable: it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice) that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is not linearly orderable. That said, suppose $X$ is any set whatsoever. Let $W(X)$ be the set of all *well*-orderings of subsets of $X$ modulo isomorphism. Then $\mathbb{W}(X)$ is well-ordered by embeddability (of representatives). Moreover, it can be shown that [there is no injection from $W(X)$ to $X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number).